# Is is possible to obtain line level with Composite/RCA connector from an ASHLY TRA-4150 Amplifier?

Tags: audio, amplifier, rca, system

I am trying to split the output of an audio channel output "mix" (there is no mixing panel between the mic inputs to amplifier and speaker).  From what I can see, it appears that there is a line level out going to a wall plate/port with RCA female connectors.  I essentially want to mimic that configuration (assuming its correct) but send it to a composite/rca splitter to then direct back to a PTZOptics streaming camera as its audio line input, rather than relying on the camera's built-in microphone.
[image]

Is this something that is possible to do?  I am assuming I need a 2-conductor 18AWG cable, crimped to 2 Y-type terminal connectors one one end and 2 (red/white) RCA/composite male connectors on the other end.

What I am not sure how to do is connect it to the outputs of the amplifier.  There is a 4/8 ohm, COM, 70V, and 100V screw-type terminals (see picture).  I ASSUME it is COM & 70V as show in the image below, but I am not confident of the labeling on the wires. Is it possible to get the output to LINE level without shorting out or frying the splitter or camera or both?

[image: Diagram]
[image: ASHLY TRA-4150 Rear]

[image: ASHLY TRA-4150 Close-up]

EDIT:  @Data Processing answered the question.  You CANNOT run 70V out to composite splitter.  I did omit a critical piece of information, however; there is a Nexia CS bi-amp whose output is going as input to the ASHLY amp.  Based on @Data Processing's input, I assume I need to take the + & - bare wires on each composite connector and insert them in an available output on the bi-amp out to the splitter and finally the camera.

[image: Nexia CS Bi-amp]
[image: Bare Wire to Composite/RCA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't wire the output of the Ashly power amp directly into an unbalanced line input.  That will likely damage something.  Your power amp accepts a line level input and produces an amplified output to drive distributed (transformer-coupled, in your case -- that's what the 70V connection is telling you) loudspeakers in a restaurant or retail store.  Your amp does not have a line output.  If you want to inject signal into a camera line input, you probably need to split the signal going *into* the amp (you don't say exactly what this signal is), not the signal coming *out* of the amp.  If the output of the amp must be used for some reason, you can purchase a 70V-to-line level adapter box ([RDL makes one](https://www.rdlnet.com/blog/tips/70v-to-unbalanced-line-level-conversion), for example) but this seems like a needless complication unless we know more about the situation.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. I don't want to edit the posting as it will actually incorrectly ask my question.  Your answer is correct - no you can't output 70V to line.

Prior to the ASHLY amp, there is a Nexia CS bi-amp signal processor.  This particular model has 10 inputs and 6 outputs.  It looks like it is +, -, and COM.  I don't know the name of the connector, but I have seen a three-conductor (I think; could be two?) to RCA/Composite male.  I assume then I could use that connector to the splitter and be on my way?

Comment: Yes, using a spare output on the Nexia CS to feed the camera input makes complete sense.  The only potential complication is that the non-used output ports on the CS may not be enabled for audio output.  Those units run a custom software program, and very often, when integrators install them, they don't turn on more outputs than they need for the job at hand.  You can always try it and see if it works, though.  You'll use the plus and ground pins (leave the minus pin unconnected) on the terminal block to the RCA male.